# While importing from keras_squeezenet import squeezenet I am getting import error

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

While importing I am getting this error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-5f3b3ff11ebd> in <module>
      5 import os
      6 from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
----> 7 from keras_squeezenet import squeezenet

~\Anaconda3\envs\python3.7-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\keras_squeezenet\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from keras_squeezenet.squeezenet import SqueezeNet
      2 from keras_squeezenet.version import __version__

~\Anaconda3\envs\python3.7-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\keras_squeezenet\squeezenet.py in <module>
----> 1 from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
      2 from keras import backend as K
      3 from keras.layers import Input, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation, concatenate, Dropout, warnings
      4 from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, GlobalMaxPooling2D
      5 from keras.models import Model

ImportError: cannot import name '_obtain_input_shape' from 'keras.applications.imagenet_utils'
```

I am using Tensorflow version 2.0.0 and keras version 2.2.4-tf

Could I import SqueezeNet model through tf.keras or any other resemblance to it?

Comment: It is a Keras version issue. You may either need to downgrade Keras or find alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

use tensorflow version 1.14.0rc1
and keras version 2.1.1
use the following in order to use pretrained squeezenet model:
**first**:
`!pip install git+https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-squeezenet.git`
**second**:
`!pip install tensorflow==1.14.0rc1`
**then**:
`!pip install q keras==2.1.1`
**finally you could use**:

```py
from keras_squeezenet import SqueezeNet
```

check the model that i have built:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nias2agRtn0G0Wn0KouJhkyTMO7IQkIS?usp=sharing
note: the link may get expired.